# Read html select value into jenkins Active Choices Reactive Parameter

Tags: html, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, html-select

I saw many examples for Active Choices Reactive Parameter using formatted html, but none of these use the HTML select input type.

Here is my html snippet (simplified input of json_files for brevity):

```
def json_files = ["a", "b", "c"]

html_to_be_rendered = """<select id="config" name="config">"""

json_files.each { json_file ->
  html_to_be_rendered = """
    ${html_to_be_rendered}
    <option value="${json_file}">${json_file}</option>
"""
}

return "${html_to_be_rendered}</select>"
```

I thought I should be able to read the selected value using ${config}, but seems that doesn't work.

This is how I define it in the jenkins GUI:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only problem you have is the `name` attribute of the `select` should be hard-coded to `value`.
no need for the `id` attribute.

Comment: This now works:

def json_files = ["a", "b", "c"]

html_to_be_rendered = """<select name="value">"""

json_files.each { json_file ->
  html_to_be_rendered = """
    ${html_to_be_rendered}
    <option value="${json_file}">${json_file}</option>
"""
}

return "${html_to_be_rendered}</select>"